# Backbone design query

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, backbone.js

I have one Backbone view MainMenuView. MainMenuModel  has an array of sub-models ItemModel. Main menu has two pages so it has next previous buttons. First page has 6 Items and second page has 5 Items. Right now I have two methods in router to go to first and second page respectively. For now I am creating model/sub-models in the App router and passing that to render method of MainMenuView. Also when I am on second page I want to disable next button and enable previous button. Similarly toggling the buttons on first page. There are click events as well. I have defined a helper to bind these events and toggling the state of buttons. Its working but doesn't look good to me. So wanted to ask if there is a better way of reusing the same view.

```
var MainMenuModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
           menuItems: []
      }
})


var MenuItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
           title: ''
      }
})


var MainMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

       render: function(){
          //_.template stuff goes here
       }

})


var App = Backbone.Router.extend({


  goToFirstPage: function(){
     MenuItemModel item1 = new MenuItemModel({title: "One"});
     MenuItemModel item2 = new MenuItemModel({title: "Two"});
     MenuItemModel item3 = new MenuItemModel({title: "Three"});
      MainMenuModel model = new MainMenuModel({menuItems: [item1, item2, item3]});

  }

   goToSecondPage: function(){
     MenuItemModel item4 = new MenuItemModel({title: "Four"});
     MenuItemModel item5 = new MenuItemModel({title: "Five"});
      MainMenuModel model = new MainMenuModel({menuItems: [item4, item5]});

  }


})

//some helper methods:

function bindEventsForFirstPage(){

        $("#prev").off('click');
        $("#prev").addClass('prev-disabled');
        $("#next").click(goToFirstPage);
    }

function bindEventsForSecondPage(){
        $("#prev").click(goToSecondPage);
        $("#next").off('click');
        $("#next").addClass('next-disabled');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple solution to use `Backbone.Collection` instead of `MainMenuModel` and use view inside `Router`

And here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/gNa2h/

**HTML**

```
<script type="x/template" id="template">
    <ul>
        <% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
            <li>
                <%= item.title %>
            </li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>

    <a id="prev" href="#" class="<% if (page === 1) { %>prev-disabled<% } %>">Prev</a>
    <a id="next" href="#" class="<% if (page === 2) { %>next-disabled<% } %>">Next</a>
</script>

<div id="menu"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.prev-disabled, .next-disabled {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var MenuItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: ''
    }
});


var MainMenuCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MenuItemModel
});


var MainMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#menu',

    template: _.template($("#template").html()),

    events: {
        'click #prev': 'onClickPrev',
        'click #next': 'onClickNext'
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.page = options.page;
        this.render();
    },

    onClickPrev: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass("prev-disabled")) {
            return false;
        }
        app.goToFirstPage();
    },

    onClickNext: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass("next-disabled")) {
            return false;
        }
        app.goToSecondPage();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            page: this.page,
            items: this.collection.toJSON()
        }));
    }
});


var App = Backbone.Router.extend({

    goToFirstPage: function() {
        var collection = new MainMenuCollection([
            { title: "One" },
            { title: "Two" },
            { title: "Three "}
        ]);

        this.view && this.view.undelegateEvents();

        this.view = new MainMenuView({
            page: 1,
            collection: collection
        });
    },

    goToSecondPage: function() {
        var collection = new MainMenuCollection([
            { title: "Four" },
            { title: "Five "}
        ]);

        this.view && this.view.undelegateEvents();

        this.view = new MainMenuView({
            page: 2,
            collection: collection
        });        
    }

});

var app = new App();

app.goToFirstPage();
```

P.S. it is not very good solution but I just tried to show you how you can use collection and reuse view. If the number of pages will grow I'd add collection for them.

**Edit**

And here is refactored version with multi page support http://jsfiddle.net/gNa2h/2/